# Should I use lazy loading for my custom UIViews?

Tags: swift

I'm currently working on a social media app. One of the ViewControllers has several UIViews on it and I currently instantiate each and every view whenever the user goes to this ViewController. It eats up memory and sometimes, the Views go unused. I don't want to be wasteful, so I was curious if each UIView that isn't immediately presented, should be a lazy variable? Are there any caveats to having UIViews lazy loaded?

Furthermore every example I see using lazy loading is either a label or a manager object of some sort; so my question is, if my UIView is pretty complex(has a UITableView/UICollectionView), should I be doing the UIView instantiation on the main thread?

Comment: I think that is more of a trade-off question. You need to decide between fast start vs fast view transition. It also boils down to what happens during initialization in your views.

Comment: @zatta thank you for answering; i guess i'll really have to think about this. Because my problem is when i go to this view, my memory jumps up from ~20 to ~50...and when i pop it off the stack, it hovers around ~40. So there's something fishy happening there...